# Setup Cloud 9 for Google Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine, cloud9-ide

I am trying to access Compute Engine from Cloud 9, but I need the HOSTNAME and SSH keys for my server. How do I find them?

Cloud nine needs node but has auto detect. Initial Path and Port are optional, but I have no idea what to put.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to www.whatismyip.com from the shell of your GCE machine to see your IP. You can use vi to edit ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and add your key there. If you have node installed via a typical package manager, cloud9 should be able to find your node path. Initial path and port can be as they are.

Comment: So my IP is the hostname? I am a little confused since cloud9 shows me an SSH key on the setup panel, I have to give that SSH key to GCE or get and SSH from GCE and pass it to c9?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your GCE instance's IP from the Google Developer Console:
https://console.developers.google.com

You want the **External** IP.